# Create dynamic number of layouts with contents by code in Android

Tags: java, android, layout

on my activity, I want to create a dynamic number of linear layouts following one by one horizontally (in the attached example I try to create 3 horizontal layouts in doing loop, each contains a text and a button and should be displayed one by one inside parent vertical linear layout)

the following code gives results shown on the screenshot. the last layout in loop rewrites all others

```
    for(int kkk = 0; kkk < 4; kkk++) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        textView.setText("Text number" + kkk);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 42);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        button.setText("Button!" + kkk);
        button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
        linearLayout.addView(button);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
```

[the result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znZdO.png)

What should I do to create layouts in doing the loop as is shown on the screen with a red mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With loop you're creating all those layouts but because of everytime loop works you're setting as a content view because of that the last layout of the loop becomes parent layout and your content view.
Outside loop, create one parent layout and set as a content view. Inside loop, add other layouts to parent layout.

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  
for(int kkk = 0; kkk < 4; kkk++) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
    textView.setText("Text number" + kkk);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 42);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
    button.setText("Button!" + kkk);
    button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
    linearLayout.addView(button);
    parent.addView(linearLayout);
}
setContentView(parent);
```

Note: Loop will work 4 times. That  means you'll have 4 same layout (it starts with 0 and ends with 3). If you want 3 layouts you should change the range.

```
for(int kkk = 0; kkk < 3; kkk++) {
}
```

or

```
for(int kkk = 1; kkk < 4; kkk++){
}
```

**Edit**

> What if I need to set as a parent the layout that exists already in
> xml instead of creation?

Set your xml, create an instance for layout (which you want to add your child views in to it) and find with its ID so you can use it with Java codes.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.idOfLayout);
for(int kkk = 0; kkk < 4; kkk++) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    ...
    parent.addView(linearLayout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfect. What if I need to set as a parent the layout that exists already in xml instead of creation?

Comment: Editted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new XML with a single row UI. and Inflate this xml when onClick or method call.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);


                text1 = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                text2 = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
```